# jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 datepicker data-role="date" not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, datepicker

`<input data-role="date" type="text">` It doesn't work when I click on it.
http://jsfiddle.net/geoyws/7KRD9/1/

Am I missing something? When I click on the field, there is no datepicker popup.

Comment: The datepicker widget is not part of jQuery Mobile and requires a third party wrapper to be supported. This wrapper is apparently missing from your fiddle. For more information, see http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/datepicker/.

Comment: This is the answer. Please answer instead of commenting next time Mr. Hamidi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this for date in Jquery mobile 1.4.1

```
<input type="date" id="date_val" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "useNewStyle":true}'>
```

this also works JQM v 1.3

Refer this fiddle output <kbd>**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2752A/17/)**</kbd>

Comment: I can't seem to get your fiddle to work. I can't click on it.

Comment: @Geoyws click the bottom of icon try this one http://jsfiddle.net/2752A/16/

Comment: still not working lol...

Comment: @Geoyws now try what you want..

Comment: Still not working. It is supposed to pop up on click.

Comment: do the same thing yaar..@Geoyws

Comment: Oh now it is working. Great. Well clicking must be the same thing. Peace. Now why does StackOverflow not let me reply you on comment? It must be buggy.

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort man. Appreciate it.