# How do you get jQuery Mobile's datepicker to pop-up in the center of the field instead of at the left?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datepicker

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geoyws/W4P25/).

HTML:

```
<input data-role="date" type="text">
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("top", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
};

$("datepickerinput").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        $(".ui-datepicker").center();
    }
});
```

I can't seem to manipulate the [beforeShow](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/datepicker/#option-beforeShow) event to make the calendar appear in the center.

Comment: Have you considered using the DateBox plugin: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/ here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/tx7k6/1/

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/W4P25/3/

Comment: thanks @Aravinth, why don't you put your comment as the answer?

Comment: are you ready to accept this one..

Comment: the concept seems to work, but could you make it really center itself?

Comment: @Geoyws what about this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376180/jquery-mobile-1-4-2-datepicker-data-role-date-not-working/22385678#22385678 are you got or not.

Comment: That one still doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this answer has the full working solution: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geoyws/W4P25/5/) (I tweaked @Aravinth's fiddle.)

```
$(document).on("click","#datepickerinputtag",function(){
    var viewportwidth = $(window).width();
    var datepickerwidth = $("#ui-datepicker-div").width();
    var leftpos = (viewportwidth - datepickerwidth)/2; //Standard centering method
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").css({left: leftpos,position:'absolute'});
});
```

Answer (score 4):

For center alignment of Date Picker try the following code. I gave 100 to left , you can this change according to yours.

```
$(document).on("click","#date1",function(){
// $("#ui-datepicker-div").attr('align', 'center');
$("#ui-datepicker-div").css({left: 100, position:'absolute'});
});
```

Refer this <kbd>**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W4P25/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: This totally works; just have to be tweaked:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geoyws/W4P25/4/)

Comment: Please refer to my answer below.

Comment: yep i suggest the same method for one of my previous answer..anyway you are using my concept right.

Comment: but you are accepted your own answer..anyway keep going

Comment: because my answer is more complete, sir

Comment: thats why i specified in answer like " you can this change according to yours." ok no issue keep going.